# If a program crashes, does linux generate a SIGHUP message?

Tags: ubuntu, kill

I have a python script on ubuntu which is occasionally being killed, not by me, and apparently not by the kernel because the logs are empty (`/var/log/kern.log`) and there is no record of the kernel terminating it when I run the `dmesg | grep -i kill` command.

So I can only suspect there is a bug causing it to crash and this generates a SIGHUP message for some reason? (Is this how programs which crash are dealt with?) To confirm or disprove this, is there somewhere I can look?

Comment: There are other options - for example, the Python script might encounter an exception and simply exit on its own. Do you have some sort of logging turned on, or are you capturing the script's standard output and error into a log file? The `SIGHUP` signal is delivered to a running process once its parent that controls the terminal exits (for example, when you just kill a shell or close the terminal with an ssh session).

Comment: I have logging enabled and all that is dumped into my log file is that a SIGHUP was received.